# ARCore – How to rotate an object around its Y axis?

Tags: java, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I wonder how to rotate an object around its Y axis.

For example, I would like to rotate the droid bot of the Google sample app hello_ar_java https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java around its Y axis with an angle alpha.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this working in a simpler way, although this doesn't handle frame rate delta properly it may be a helpful starter. In my class that extends AnchorNode I define my new Node in the class so it is available like so:

```
private Node myNode = null;
```

Then override the onUpdate as so:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    super.onUpdate(frameTime);
    if (myNode!=null){
    Quaternion q1 = myNode.getLocalRotation();
    Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0f), .2f);
    myNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.multiply(q1, q2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do something similar. In the object renderer's draw method you can add:

```
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, rotationAngle, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -x, -y, -z);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Kotlin for my answer.

Use `Quaternions` for rotation to avoid a [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). A common Quaternion rule is that the square root of the squares of the floats `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` should always equal to `1`.

```
sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) + (w * w)) = 1
```

> For rotating a cube around `Y` **Counter Clock Wise** use the following code:

```
var value: Float = 5.0

override fun onLeft(value: Float) {
    cubeNode.apply {
        Log.d("left", value.toString())
        localRotationCCW = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), value)
    }
}
```

> For rotating a cube around `Y` **Clock Wise** use the following code:

```
var value: Float = 5.0

override fun onRight(value: Float) {
    cubeNode.apply {
        Log.d("right", value.toString())
        localRotationCW = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), -value)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ARCore problem but a OpenGL ES problem. But to achieve what you want you have to add the rotation to the model matrix in ObjectRenderer.updateModelMatrix(float[] modelMatrix, float scaleFactor). How to do rotation is explained e.g. here: http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/rotation/